# using recursion to eliminate duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

i'm just starting to learn how recursion works and i keep getting stuck on what i think should be a simple question. I need to create a function using recursion that takes a list and returns a new list with only 1 of each value within the original list.

Example:
original_list = [1,1,2,3,3,4,5]
returned_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

what i have tried:

```
def recursion(list1):
    new_list = []
    if list1 == []:
       new_list = []
    else:
       if list1[0] not in list1[1:]:
          new_list = new_list.append(list1[0]) + recursion (list1[1:])
       else:
          new_list = recursion (list1[1:])
    return new_list
```

Comment: What exactly is your question ? The code seems fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing `new_list` as a parameter to the recursive function; therefore, each level of the recursion is unaware of the results you have gathered so far, and the result of the recursion is only the result of the first level.

(I'm refraining from posting the corrected code since you would presumably like to fix it yourself, and thereby learn more - let me know if you need more hints.)

Comment: appreciate it! I can only pass my function a single list and it needs to use recursion to return a new list with no duplicates of the original list. so i cant pass it new_list as a parameter.

Comment: @stacker: In that case, you need to combine the result you get from the recursive call with the result you computed locally. Think of it as laziness: your function wants to do as little work as possible (typically involving only one element), and pass the rest of the work onto the recursive call. However, it's also an option to do your part of the work _after_ the recursive call (so that you can inspect the recursive result before deciding what to do).

Comment: @stacker: You're also going to need to reverse your thinking a bit: you're currently attempting to check if the number is among the numbers you've already seen. But if you can only pass a single list as a parameter, that must necessarily be only the numbers that haven't been processed yet. So instead, you need to check if the number is among the numbers you receive from the recursive call.

Comment: @stacker: Glad to hear it! (And props for actually trying to code it yourself before asking, unlike a lot of other people who ask about homework...)